# Why does testfor sometimes output an error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Because there are so many questions asking about this, but not closed as duplicates, I decided to make a uniting question here:

There are <strike>two</strike> <strike>three</strike> four basic situations here:

- Why does the /testfor command (I have) always output an error (not listed below)?
- Why does the /testfor command (I have) always output `the entity UUID is an invalid format`?
- Why does the same /testfor command sometimes output `the entity UUID is an invalid format` instead of `found [x]` and sometimes not?
- Why does the /testfor command not output anything?

Comment: Please use this as a reference point to any other users asking something from this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the command finds no entities that fit into all the parameters and conditions you entered - it's just a false output. For example, if you enter

```
/testfor @e[type=ThisIsNotAValidEntityType]
```

it will always output an error (**case 1 above**). If you want to stop this showing, edit the command so that it "fits" at at least one entity or place an entity so that it fits the commands.

---

This command will aslo always output an error, but this time the error will always be `the entity UUID is an invalid format` (**case 2 above**):

```
/testfor @p[score_x_min=3,score_x=2]
```

---

On the other hand, if you type a command like so:

```
/testfor @e[type=Creeper,c=-1]
```

you will get a false output (`the entity UUID us an invalid format`) only if the farthest entity from you isn't a Creeper (**case 3 above**).

---

But, if your testfor command **may theoretically target more entities**, and doesn't, eg.

```
/testfor @e[type=Creeper]
/testfor @e[score_x_min=3,score_x=2]
```

then you will not get *any* output at all (**case 4 above**).

Comment: "`/testfor @e[type=ThisIsNotAValidEntityType]`" will output `Entity type 'ThisIsNotAValidEntityType' is invalid`, not `The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`.

Comment: @colorfusion Ah, fixed that. Now it should be OK. Thanks for noticing me.

Comment: `/testfor @e[score_x_min=3,score_x=2]` & `/testfor @e[type=Creeper]` - These commands will not actually output anything at all if there were no targets found, due to how the command parser cycles through targets. Selectors that are **not** size-limited to 1 target (`@p`, `@e[c=1]`, `@a[c=1]`, `@r`) will not provide error output if no targets were found. If the selector is limited to 1 target, then you'll receive the error.

Comment: @Skylinerw What about `/testfor @p[score_x_min=3,score_x=2]` and `/testfor @e[type=Creeper,c=1]`

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek Yep, those will produce the error (the first one does due to `@p` limiting to 1 target, and the second one due to `c=1` being specified).

Comment: @Skylinerw I edited it in; I hope it's OK now.